# Use Greasemonkey to change Text to Images (on a static site)?

Tags: javascript, image, greasemonkey

Is it possible to use Greasemonkey to change text links on a page to actual images, and also to modify those links?

Let's say there's a table on a page that is displaying a bunch of filenames in the second column like this: `<tr><td></td><td><a href="wwwlala001.html">wwwlala001.jpg</a></td>`...`</tr>`). Is it possible to have it so that when the page loads, all of the filenames (not the links) in the second column like wwwlala001.jpg change to this?:

```
<img src="http://domain.com/images/wwwlala001.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
```

I tried modifying the code here, but I had no luck:

```
    // ==UserScript==
// @name    _Image delinker
// @include http://dotup.org
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant   GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

var imageExtensions = ["gif", "png", "jpg", "jpeg"];
var imgExtRegex     = new RegExp(
    '\\.(' + imageExtensions.join ('|') + ')$', 'i'
);

/*-- Tune the CSS path, for each site, to only find links that can be
    the image links you care about.
*/
//-- For forums.hardwarezone.com.sg
waitForKeyElements ("page div > a", delinkImage);

function delinkImage (jNode) {
    var imgUrl  = jNode.attr ("href");

    if (imgExtRegex.test (imgUrl) ) {
        //-- Found an image link.  Replace contents.
        jNode.html (
            '<img src="http://domain.com/images/' + imgUrl
            + '" width="200" height="200" class="gmDeLinked" alt="GM replaced image">'
        );
    }
}

GM_addStyle ( "                                 \
    img.gmDeLinked {                            \
        border:             1px solid lime;     \
        max-width:          90vw;               \
    }                                           \
" );
/*
Exception: waitForKeyElements is not defined
@Scratchpad/2:18
*/
```

Thank you!

Comment: It says "Exception: waitForKeyElements is not defined
@Scratchpad/2:18"

Comment: That error means that you changed the script in a way not shown above (is that initial indent on `// ==UserScript==` there? It would bust the script), or there was an installation error.  Uninstall the script and then reinstall it.  What OS, FF version and GM version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the classic, simple approach for a *static* site, using jQuery:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _image delinker, static site
// @include  http://dotup.org/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

var imageExtensions = ["gif", "png", "jpg", "bmp"];
var imgExtRegex     = new RegExp(
    '\\.(' + imageExtensions.join ('|') + ')$', 'i'
);

//-- This jQuery selector is custom for each new site...
var imgLinks    = $("table tr td > a")
//-- Also custom for the site...
var urlBase     = "http://www.dotup.org/uploda/";

//-- Remove non-image links.
imgLinks.filter ( function() {
    return imgExtRegex.test (this.textContent);
} );

imgLinks.each ( function () {
    var jThis       = $(this);  // This is one of the links
    var filename    = $.trim (jThis. text () );

    //-- Rreplace link content with image:
    jThis.html (
        '<img src="' + urlBase + filename + '" height="200" />'
    );
} );
```

---

Notes:

1. **NEVER** use `@include *` for this kind of script!
2. This assumes that the image base URL is always the same.
3. The initial selector should be tuned to the site, to avoid unpleasant side effects.
4. If you hammer *some* sites, like this for a lot of rapid image requests, they will throttle you.  You'll only get a few images, and/or you'll get banned/blocked.
5. Setting both the height and width like that will distort most images.  Just set one or the other.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! How do I add more image types like JPG, gif, GIF, bmp, BMP, png, PNG, etc.? Thank you so much!

Comment: See the updated answer. Note that the values of `imageExtensions` are *not* case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

I am not much of a userscript expert, but I had a script from [here](http://www.sitzmar.com/blog/software/greasemonkey-image-relinker). The original site is down, but here's the script.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Inline Image Relinker
// @namespace     /web/20070712085327/http://www.sitzmar.com
// @description   Replaces links to images with the actual image
// @include       *
// ==/UserScript==

(function() 
{
    function getXPath(p, context) 
    { 
        var arr = new Array(); 
        var xpr = document.evaluate(p,context,null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

        for(i = 0;item = xpr.snapshotItem(i); i++)
        { 
            arr.push(item); 
        } 

        return arr; 
    }

    doc = window.document;
    var xpath = "//A[(contains(@href, '.jpg') or contains(@href, '.jpeg') or contains(@href, '.gif') or contains(@href, '.bmp') or contains(@href, '.png')) and not(contains(@href, '.php') or contains(@href, '.asp'))]";

    results = getXPath(xpath, doc);

    for(i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
    {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        var source = results[i].getAttribute("href");

        img.setAttribute("src", source);
        img.setAttribute("class", "what");
        results[i].textContent = "";
        results[i].appendChild(img);
    }
}
)();
```

Comment: Thanks! When I try that though I get a "Exception: syntax error
@Scratchpad/2:1"

Comment: Yay that worked! Is there a way to add something before the filename though, like /upload/?

Comment: Yeah, I want to add more to the URL before the filename.

Comment: You have the URL here `var source = results[i].getAttribute("href");` you can modify this before setting as the image `src`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I'm really new to this. ^_^;; Where would I edit in the part I want on that line?